# showing multiple content on single page?

Tags: php

Is it possible to show multiple videos on a single page? I mean like I have a couple of videos and I am tired of creating single page for each of 'em and what I want is the way youtube does . can I just create single page and put a link to each video and stream them on a single page? any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Inspect youtube source.

Comment: No, it's an impossible feat that mankind will never be able to accomplish.

Comment: I just don't get it why I am getting down votes, I just asked a question.

Comment: @user2510039: The answer to your question would cover half of a book so you are getting down votes.

Comment: Joking aside, your question is vague and lacks the specific requirements for a proper question on StackOverflow.  If you have specific programming question then you must outline what you've tried, where you are stuck and what you are trying to accomplish.  By saying "I want to show multiple videos on a page" you are essential asking this community to do all the work for you.  Do some research of your own, and when you get stuck at a certain point, THEN ask.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but you need to use a serverside scripting language, like PHP.

Comment: I know a little bit of php, so what should I do?

Comment: Learn PHP. If you have a specific question we can help you but as it is your question is too broad.